# Opencart Paypal - Pay without paypal account

Tags: paypal, opencart

I have an opencart system with paypal payments. Is there an option to allow user a (credit card) payment without forced paypal account registration. So far i use paypal standard module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With PayPal Standard you don't have a lot of control of what displays on the PayPal landing page. Sometimes your users will be able to use guest checkout, other times not.

If you switched to OpenCart's ExpressCheckout module you could possibly enable this feature. However, you would need to add a variable to the `SetExpressCheckout` call.

In the version of OpenCart I have, `\upload\catalog\controller\payment\pp_express.php` contains an array with the `SetExpressCheckout` method. You would need to add `'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'SOLE',` to this array.

Using the ExpressCheckout module and modifying it in this way should enable guest checkout every time.

If you want to make the guest checkout option the primary option, you can also set LANDINGPAGE=Billing and USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard.  This will handle both the old and new Express Checkout pages, and force the credit card from (guest checkout) to show up by default instead of the login.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart supports most of PayPal's payment products, including several that will allow you to process direct credit card payments. Some may require an additional Opencart extension.